# how to add if else condition in batch class

Tags: batch

Based on the requirement  i have a Batch Class .

Small info needed ...in query locator i have given the conditions for all needed .Now i would like to add if - else condition for one of the condition used in query .Can i use it .

If SRR = Yes --- email should go ,If SRR = No -- stop sending email.

How can i use it

Code :

```
global class NotificationEmail implements Database.Batchable < sObject >, Schedulable, Database.Stateful {
    global List<String> errorMessages = new List<String>();
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

        Date ed = Date.today().addDays(150);
        System.debug(Date.today().addDays150));

        set<Id> setContractIds = new set<Id>();

        for(Contract_role__c objContract: [SELECT  Contract__c FROM Contract_role__c WHERE Role__c = 'SA' AND Contract__r.EndDate =: ed]) {
            setContractIds.add(objContract.Contract__c);
        }

         return Database.getQueryLocator([Select  id, Contract_Name__c , EndDate ,Contact_Email__c, Contract_End_Date_2__c,  Account.Owner.Email ,Contact__r.ID FROM Contract  WHERE Id IN: setContractIds AND Renewable__c =True AND Send_Renewal_Reminder__c ='YES' ]);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List < Contract > recs) {
        List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > mailList = new List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > ();
        for (Contract c: recs) {
            if (c.Contact_Email__c != null && SRR__c ='YES' ) {
                List < String > toAddresses = new List < String > ();
                List < String > CcAddresses = new List < String > ();
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                ccAddresses.add(c.Account.Owner.Email);

                mail.setCcAddresses(CcAddresses);
                mail.setTargetObjectId(c.Contact__r.ID);
                mail.setWhatId(c.Id);
                mail.setTemplateId('00X4B000000M2i8');
                mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

                mailList.add(mail);

            }
            else if (c.Contact_Email__c != null && SendRR__c ='NO')
            {
                **stop sending email Notification**
             }
         }
         Messaging.sendEmail(mailList);
    }


    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        AsyncApexJob aaj = [Select Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed, MethodName, TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email from AsyncApexJob where Id =:BC.getJobId()];

        // Send an email to the Apex job's submitter notifying of job completion.
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {aaj.CreatedBy.Email};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setSubject('JOB Salesforce Thirty Days NotificationEmailtoCustomer Finished: ' + aaj.Status);
        String bodyText='Total Job Items ' + aaj.TotalJobItems + ' Number of records processed ' + aaj.JobItemsProcessed + ' with '+ aaj.NumberOfErrors + ' failures.\n';
        bodyText += 'Number of Error Messages ' + errorMessages.size() + '\n';
        bodyText += 'Error Message' + String.join(errorMessages, '\n');
        mail.setPlainTextBody(bodyText);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }

    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        NotificationEmailtoAccountExecutive batchable = new NotificationEmailtoAccountExecutive();
        database.executebatch(batchable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use it since you're only sending emails to the contacts that haven't opted out. there's no need to use the `else if` condition in this situation. At best you could add a debug statement for each email address that you didn't send an email to.

Comment: :Thanks for the response.But their are other email notifications going out  based on the days and their would like to have the else if condition .Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: As I said, just add a debug statement with whatever info you want to include and + 'Opt out = true'. Without knowing your use case, or how you might want to record that an email was to send to all other users but these ones who opted out, I don't know what you want me to tell you. It's not needed, but you can keep it there. What to do inside it is up to you. Adding a debug statement to your log is the only thing that makes sense to me. It tells you that the record was "touched".

Comment: :Thanks for your information .When i use if condition as if(c.Contact_Email__c != null && SendRR__c ='NO') ,the system throws an error as AND operator should contain a boolean expression.

Comment: Is SendRR__c a boolean? If so, it's values should be true and false. In your first `if` statement, you should be using `true` and in the 2nd using `false` with `'=='`.